# Trouble removing NA from a df column

Tags: r

I am trying to find the mean of a column in my df without getting `NA` errors. However, even though I state `na.rm = TRUE`, my console keeps giving Warning messages like this:

> 1: In mean.default(inte, na.rm = TRUE) :
> argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

I have tried different methods of column selection like `$` and `[]`, but this doesn't seem to be the problem. I am a beginner, but shouldn't `na.rm = TRUE` remove all values that are `NA`?

(as far as I am concerned, you will find the problem in line 8)

```r
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332) {
    means <- c()
    for(i in id) {
        x <- paste(getwd(), "/", directory, "/", sprintf("%03d", i), ".csv", sep = "")
        freem <- read.csv(x)
        inte <- freem$pollutant
        means[i] <- mean(inte, na.rm = TRUE)
    }
    mean(means)
}
```

I expect the code to return the mean of the selected column, without any `NA`'s

Comment: What is the output of `class(freem$pollutant)`

Comment: Using `readr::read_csv` instead of `read.csv` should help

Comment: Yes, the function `mean(inte, na.rm=TRUE)` will work even if there are NAs in `inte`. The source of your problem is somewhere else. Inspect the vector `inte` and work backwards from there.

Comment: As Sonny pointed out you should check the class of your column. Your error seems to indicate that your column is not being read in as a numeric. How do you take the average of a string (or other). This could happen if your data has characters in it to indicate things such as (10*, 10F, na). An NA value in R is generally when you read in a missing value in the csv. `10,,15` might be read in as `10,NA,15` as a numeric column whereas `10,na,15` might be read in as `10,"na",15` as a character column. Also, 10* or 10F would always be read in as a character column.

Comment: @sonny the type appears to be 'closure', that doesn't seem right indeed! Thank you all for responding so soon!

Comment: The problem is almost certainly with your data. You should load one instance of `freem`, confirm that `mean(freem$pollutant)` gives the same error, and then [edit] your question to add the results of `str(freem)`.